# How to get keyboard control key in Gma.UserActivityMonitor (C#)?

Tags: c#, dll

I hook keyboard event using:

```
HookManager.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyUp);
```

Then wait for keyboar event by:

```
public void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    StepInfo step = new StepInfo();
    step.keyALT = e.Alt;
    step.keyCTRL = e.Control;
    step.keySHIFT = e.Shift;
    step.KeyHandle = e.Handled;
    step.keySuppress = e.SuppressKeyPress;
    step.keyCode = e.KeyCode;
    step.keyData = e.KeyData;
    step.keyValue = e.KeyValue;
    step.modifiers = e.Modifiers;
}
```

I want to check the combination key <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> and other control key.
Example: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> .. etc
But I all e.KeyData, it return only letter key like A, B, C but the e.Alt, e.Shift, and e.Control always be "false" value.

How can I check that, does user press <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You may find **GetKeyboardState** function useful in your case:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx

Implementation could be like this:

```
  [DllImport("User32.dll",
             EntryPoint = "GetKeyboardState",
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal static extern Boolean CoreGetKeyboardState(Byte[] value);

  public static Boolean IsKeyDown(Keys key) {
    Byte[] data = new Byte[256];

    if (!CoreGetKeyboardState(data))
      return false;

    return ((data[(int) key] & 0x80) == 0x80);
  }

  ...

  if (IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && 
      (IsKeyDown(key.Menu) || IsKeyDown(key.ShiftKey) || IsKeyDown(key.ControlKey))) {
    //TODO: You code here  
  }
```